# Image not showing up using <img> HTML

Tags: html, ruby

I am building an app using Ruby on Rails and for my user page, I am having trouble generating an image on my site using image tag: `<img></img>`

Here's the line of code I wrote for pulling out the image:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="logo.png" alt="Card image cap">
```

Comment: is logo.png located in root directory or it is in image folder ??

Comment: What is the image path relative to the site being loaded?

Answer (score 0):

is logo.png located in root directory or it is in image folder ??

```
 <img class="card-img-top" src="imagefoldername/logo.png" alt="Card image cap">
```